# Заполнение двумерного массива случайными числами с++

Tags: c++, массивы, случайные-числа

Создается массив случайного размера, который заполняется случайными числами.
Почему-то каждая строка получается одинаковой.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int m, n;
    float arr[m][n];

    srand(time(0));
    m=3+(rand()%4);
    n=4+(rand()%4);
    //заполнение массива от -10 до 10
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
         arr[i][j]=rand() % 21 - 10;
        }
    } 
    //вывод чисел
    cout << "Array: " << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    } 
    /* проверка размера
    cout << m << endl;
    cout << n << endl; */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во - первых, этот код не скомпилируется. Вы задаёте размер двумерному массиву переменными, которые не являются константами. Так работать не будет, т.к. размер статического массива определяется на этапе компиляции.

Во - вторых, если Вы всё же хотите задавать массив динамически, то вы можете выделять динамическую память, тем самым создавать так называемые *динамические массивы*. При использовании динамической памяти следует не забывать о последующем её освобождении после использования, дабы избежать утечек:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(0));

    int m, n;

    m = 3 + (rand() % 4);
    n = 4 + (rand() % 4);
    float ** arr = new float*[m]; // создание динамического двумерного массива на m строк
    for (int i(0); i < m; i++) // создание каждого одномерного массива в динамическом двумерном массиве, или иначе - создание столбцов размерность n
        arr[i] = new float[n];


    //заполнение массива от -10 до 10
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 21 - 10;
        }
    }
    //вывод чисел
    cout << "Array: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i(0); i < m; i++) // освобождение памяти каждого одномерного массива в двумерном массиве - удаление столбцов
        delete arr[i];
    delete arr; // освобождение памяти двумерного массива

    return 0;
}
```